# Backtrace an infinite loop (maximum execution exceeded)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm developing a small web application on top of CodeIgniter. It's so small that there is nearly no possibility that it exceeds the maximum execution time. I'm guessing that there is some kind of infinite loop. The Fatal error only tells the line number without a backtrace. Also the file producing the fatal error varies. (Sometimes it's the db, some other time it's one of my functions)

**Therefore, how to debug such an fatal error? As far as I know there is no possibility to catch a fatal error in order to print the backtrace.**

Further information - the error is sometimes pointing to this function:

```
    private function assertValidKey($key, $try = true) {
        if(!isset($this->data[$key])) {
            //Check if it needs my prefix
            if($try && is_digit($key)) {
                try {
                    return $this->assertValidKey($this->prefix.$key, false);
                }
                catch (LogicException $e) {}
                }
                throw new LogicException("Couldn't find \"{$key}\""); 
            }
        return $key;
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you are not escaping the mid-string single quote in `'Couldn't find "'.$key.'"'`, as in `'Couldn\'t find "'.$key.'"'`

Comment: @Wolf this is not an issue, but you are correct. I suggested edit original post to solve this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found a solution by myself. The PHP extension XDebug will show a backtrace. Therefore I managed to fix my infinite loop.

Comment: Out of curiosity: What was the cause of the infinite loop?